# Visual Studio 2008 - Where is the modifiers property of a control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I need to change the scope of a control from friend to public in my user control - what happened to the Modifiers property of a control?  I don't see it in the property sheet.  How am I supposed to change the scope of my controls now (besides going into the designer file and changing it in the auto-generated code)?

Comment: In general, there are many who believe that exposing an instance variable (which a control is) through a public interface is bad practice. I would count myself among these people. Try creating a property that exposes the control instead.

Comment: You are correct and I am also in that camp.  I hadn't made the relationship between this and that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option is to create a public property to expose the control or a subset of the control's own properties.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I just verified that the Modifiers row is still present under the Design group in VS2008 with WinForms and C#.  I am running VS2008 SP1.

Have you tried switching to alphabetical mode and seeing if it's listed there?  Which control are you using (I tried Button)

Comment: It might be there in WinForms and that's where I remember seeing it, but I don't see it with WebForms.

Comment: @Mike C, yes I was definitely refering to WinForms